# How to insert graph in windows form using .net C#?

Tags: c#, .net, graph

I want to insert a live graph in my bandwidth monitor tool. Can any one help me to insert a simple graph in my form using .net C#?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Chart control visualizes your data. It displays data in your Windows Forms program as a bar graph or chart. 
Please refer these link i think it will help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2210/Tracker-A-Windows-Form-graph-control

http://www.dotnetperls.com/chart

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/451281/simple-line-graph-charting